# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition - Minimum Setup

Tags: installation, sql-server, sql, setup, deployment

We have a corporate license for Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition and for time to time I have to install (or re-install it) on different Servers and computers. The setup folder size is about 2.68 GB and if I compress it with WinRAR it can be 2.05 GB.

Is there any solution to reduce the total setup files size, all what I need it is the Database Engine Services feature only. No need to install the other features as our Enterprise system doesn't require it.

I googled to find a solution to remove the unnecessary features to reduce the total setup size but I couldn't find one.

My Idea was to remove these unnecessary features setup files to be easy for me to copy the Minimum Setup files quickly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mount the `.ISO` image, and browse to the `.\setup\` folder, there are separate installers for each component.

Adding the 'Subject' column to Windows Explorer will help guide which one you want.

[image]

It's **probably** the files in `.\Setup\sql_engine_core_shared_msi`

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Aslo, I did the same with Setup\S14\1033_ENU_LP\x64\Setup and Setup\S14\1033_ENU_LP\redist

You are great, you saved my day. Thanks a lot.